# Awesomium Access Violation When Accessing HTML5 File System API

Tags: wpf, html, awesomium, html5-filesystem

### Update #1

For clarity, and easier reading, the following line is the smallest code in an HTML5 application to cause my Awesomium to crash

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(webkitStorageInfo.PERSISTENT,1,function() {}, function() {});
```

### The Details

I'm new to Awesomium, and I was hoping that maybe someone else has come across this before, or might have an idea how to fix it.

I'm creating a **WPF Application** with a [**Awesomium WebControl**](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Windows_Controls_WebControl.htm) for **Awesomium 1.7.3**. One of the webpages that I'm using within it uses the [**HTML5 FileSystem API**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

When I ran my application in **Visual Studio's debug mode**, I would attempt to perform the functionality in the HTML5 app that would use the **FileSystem API**. As soon as this would happen, I would get this pop up:

[image: vshost32.exe has stopped working A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will now close the program and notify you if a solution is available.]

If I clicked the **Debug** button, it would get this warning dialog instead:

[image: A debugger is attached to but not configured to debug this unhandled exception. To debug this exception, detach the current debugger.]

I had a look in the **Windows Event Viewer**, and found an `Error` for this.

```
Faulting application name: GeocortexApp.Windows.vshost.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x5011d445
Faulting module name: awesomium.dll, version: 1.7.3.0, time stamp: 0x52698ef3
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00a6d8a6
Faulting process id: 0x31c4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cee6500cc5ec54
Faulting application path:    C:\Development\GeocortexApp\_Trunk\GeocortexApp.Windows\bin\Debug\GeocortexApp.Windows.vshost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Awesomium.Core\v4.0_1.7.3.0__e1a0d7c8071a5214\awesomium.dll
Report Id: c8d0cd0d-5244-11e3-be84-b8ca3aa5c3db
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I debugged my **HTML5 Web Application** and was able to trace the issue down to a single line:

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, successFunction, errorFunction);
```

As soon as I execute this single line of code, it brings down my **WPF Application**. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familier with Awesomium or WPF.

However, I do know that your target line of HTML5 javascript for the File-System API was deprecated nearly 6 months ago. Also, the new code for that line would be the following or something very similar.

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024, 
  function(grantedBytes){
  window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, successFunction, errorFunction);
}, errorFunction);
```

OR (the difference being `successFunction` which would do the File-system request. I'm assuming the following would be the correct call, but again I'm not familier with everything else)

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024,successFunction,errorFunction);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ArtyMcFly. Awesomium is based on Chrome 18, so ya, not surprised to see that it's using deprecated methods :)